# Manual install package but can't find texmf directory

Tags: packages

I want to install `slashbox` package on mac os sierra and im using texmaker as editor. I can't install it from `tex live utility` because its not a registered package. So I have to install it manually. I searched on how to do it, and I found that I have to place the package .sty file in the `texmf`directory. The problem is that I can't find this directory anywhere on my device.

Comment: Open the file manager and direct to your current tex project. Put the `sty` file into this directory.

Comment: You have to install it in your `texmf-local` directory, respecting the TDS architecture (`texmf-local/tex/latex/slashbox/slashbox.sty` and `texmf-local/doc/latex/slashbox/slashbox.pdf`). But why don't you use `diagbox` which is in TeX Live?

Comment: @Bernard thanks for the hint, I didn't know about `diagbox`I will use it.

Comment: @EddyG maybe this can help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1138/177

Comment: Your personal packages should be put in your personal texmf folder which will be located in ~/Library/texmf: note the ~ which means you start in your HOME folder rather than the root folder of your hard drive (or SSD). To go to your ~/Library folder you can press the Option key and click on the Go menu in Finder and there will be a new item there for that folder. Finally, you must create the chain texmf/tex/latex chain of folders the first time you want to use them. Then add a sub-folder there to hold your package file(s). Please also read the "What is Installed" document in /Application/TeX.

Comment: @HerbSchulz thanks, I didn't have it created, and I didn't know that I have to create it for the first time.